# vim add files opened via CLI to :e history

Tags: file, vim, history, command-line-interface

In Vim by default when you enter `:e` and hit the up arrow, it shows a list of files previously opened using the `:e` command. Is there a way to add files that I've opened from the terminal via `vim <filename>` to this list as well?

Comment: Not sure if this solves your problem, but `:buffers` might be interesting for you. Also, there are some nice plugins that might help you out with finding files, like `Command-T`.

Comment: Are you interesting in upping your `history` value? Add something like `set history=1000` to `~/.vimrc`. Vim defaults to 20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility:

```
au BufEnter * for f in argv() | call histadd( "cmd", "e " . f ) | endfor
```

Explanation:

```
au                                # Autocommand.
BufEnter                          # Run it after entering a buffer.
*                                 # For any file matching.
for f in argv()                   # Select files in argument list.
call histadd( "cmd", "e " . f )   # Append to history of ex commands (beginning 
                                  # with colon) letter 'e' (of edit) with file name.
endfor                            # Repeat next loop.
```

Put that command in your `vimrc` file and try.

Answer (score 2):

I don't  think so. The  `:e <up>`  is just a  convenient way of  browsing your
history of ex commands. It's not specific to the edit command. It just happens
that  when you  type the  beginning  of an  ex  command, the  history will  be
"filtered" to the entries which begin with the same characters.

The [`:args`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#%3aargs)  command will print the  list of files given  as arguments in
the command-line, and [`:arge`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#%3aarge) will edit a file and put it in the argument
list (if isn't already).

Alternatively, the  [`:b`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#%3ab) command can be  used to enter a  buffer (in case
you still have the file in a buffer and want to edit it.

One of these might help you!